# How to control positions of views by adding it in FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add a lot of views in randomly position at Framelayout and I want to control that elements do not overlap each other! How can i do it?

Comment: add some more description to your question, what ways have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying onGlobalLayoutListener() and calculate some results, but it's still don't work. All of my attempts were limited to what I just considered height and width of view and and all is not right. (sorry for my English)